# Are recursive functions resource-intensive by nature?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I was looking at w3schools web worker page, and noticed this code:

```
var i=0;

function timedCount()
{
i=i+1;
postMessage(i);
setTimeout("timedCount()",500);
}

timedCount();
```

Two questions:

1. Is this considered a recursive function?
2. If it is, is it resource-intensive?

I'm not fully clear on the nature of recursive functions yet, but I remember hearing that every recursive call gets stored in the memory somewhere. Is this true for all recursive functions? Will that function eventually clog up the memory if it runs for long enough?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is *not* recursive, since `timedCount` exits before the next instance is invoked.
It's just a self-perpetuating delayed loop, if you want to call it that. (BTW, that would be much better handled using `setInterval` instead of repeatedly using `setTimeout`. That example is some pretty bad code, as are most [W3Fools](http://w3fools.com) resources.)

```
timedCount() -> setTimeout() -> end
    ^                |
    |                |
    +----------------+
```

*This* is a recursive function:

```
function recurse() {
    recurse();
}
```

Here a *call stack* is built up, the outer `recurse` will not exit and go off the stack until the inner `recurse` call returns, which won't return until its inner `recurse` call returns etc. ad infinitum. Since there is no `return` anywhere here, this will eventually blow the stack; so there's your resource use.

```
recurse() -> recurse() -> recurse() -> recurse() -> recurse() -> ...
```

Answer (score 2):

In general recursion can be optimised, but you can safely assume javascript implementations do no optimisation for recursion.

Regarding your two specific questions:

1. This is not strictly a recursive function. A recursive function calls itself somewhere in the function body. The function timedCount always returns control and never calls itself directly or indirectly. In this case it returns control to the page's event loop to be called again later by the timer.
2. This means it does try to ensure itself will be called again but because it isn't calling itself directly it will not fill stack space. Therefore it will not clog up the memory over time.

The impotant thing for timedCount is that it cannot be called again before it is returned.
Disregarding parallelism.

Comment: See deceze's answer for actually decent examples.

Comment: There is no parallelism in JavaScript anyway.

Comment: @millimoose Generally yes, but there has been interest in it as a potential speed up factor. I remember something with a parallelised particle engine in javascript. And of course there is the Parallel.js API. I know... this all has nothing to do with the original question.

Comment: I was being too categoric I guess, I mean there's Web Workers etc. But generally unless you're actively going for it, "regular old JS" will execute serially.

Answer (score 1):

Every function is in memory somewhere.

*Truly* recursive functions consume stack space for every call (like every other function), what matters is how many *times* it recurses.

I don't consider the example "recursive" because the original call to `timedCount` *ends* before it's called again after the timer expires. If it looked like this:

```
function timedCount() {
  i = i + 1;
  postMessage(i);
  timedCount();
}
```

that'd be recursive, and would blow your stack very quickly since there's no terminatal condition.